# path command in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm having difficulty utilizing the l1-magic and WaveLab matlab toolboxes (these are 3rd party). My main difficulty is loading the solvers etc with the path command.

I've unpacked the respective files into the MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox folder and added these to the path via File->Set Path.

My scripts keep on failing on the

```
path(path, './Optimization')
```

or

```
path(path, './Data')
```

lines and won't recognise any functions contained therein.

Is there anything I've missed out?

Comment: If you've already "added these to the path via File->Set Path" then why are you calling `path` in your scripts? Are the files in your path or not? Run `path` and look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been stupid: the ./ notation is for UNIX/Linux, I just specified the entire Windows string and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

matlab's toolbox is often in some compressed format, and its developers might have a "readme" file that details on how to install it. but, usual way to attempt installation is to place the toolbox in any directory on your drive, and then add it to Matlab path, e.g., going to File -> Set Path... -> Add Folder or Add with Subfolders. In another way, you can extract all ".m" files in your working directory, obviously you must do that for every project that you want use this downloaded toolbox.